# Finding the equivalence between free variables in an underdetermined system?

Tags: real-analysis, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, trees

Assume that I have a nonlinear, non-trivial under-determined system of the sort

$$4a+b^2+\sin(c)=5 \tag 1$$
$$b-c^2+d=3 \tag 2$$

It is my goal to find the rules between the parameters by which we can obtain solutions to the under-determined system of equations. A simple way would, of course, be to simply re-order the equations above, so that we have for each parameter something like:

$$a = 5-b^2-\sin(c)$$

Unfortunately, this only seems to work for the parameters $a$ and $d$ - for the parameters $b$ and $c$ we have more than one option to express it in terms of other variables. Hence my questions:

1. Is there a recommended, structured way of finding these equivalence relations even when they occur in multiple equations?
2. Is there a way of creating a [node tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) of sorts to see how the other parameters change if we fix one of the previously free parameters?

(The real system I am interested in is a LOT more complicated, and I want to see what happens if I fix different free parameters.)